# How to post ESP32CAM image and data to Node-Red so it arrives as payload?

Tags: upload, esp32, node-red

I have a Kodular (Android) App that posts images and related data to Node-Red.
Both image and data arrive as payload.
I also have a html script that does the same (script below) and works perfectly.
Now I would like to use ESP32CAM to post images and related data to the same Node-Red flow.

Image and data actually arrive at Node-Red but instead of arriving as msg.payload they arrives as msg.req.headers(for the data) and msg.req.files[0].buffer (for the image).

HTML script (works OK image and data inside msg.payload)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
 <head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://alprbr.com/images/car.png">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>ALPRBRAPI</title>
</head>
<body onload='startFunc()'>
<form id="myForm">
<table align='center' style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><td align="center"><font size = "5"><b>Leitura de Placas Direto ALPRBR</b></font><br>
Escolher imagem onde apareça legível a placa de um veículo:<br>
Padrão Mercosul: LLLNLNN, padrão antigo LLL-NNNN</td></tr>

<tr><td align='center'>
<input id="inpFile" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg" onclick='enableUpload()'>
<button id='btn_uploadfile' name='btn_uploadfile' type="submit">Enviar</button>
</td></tr>

<tr><td align='center'>Seu Token: <input id="myToken" name="myToken" minlength='32' maxlength='32'>
<a href="https://alprbr.com/signup.html" title="Cadastro de Usuários">Não Tenho</a>
<br>Incluir Dados do Veículo? 
<input id="vehicledata" type="checkbox" checked />
</td></tr>

<tr><td align="center"><img src="#" id="localImage" width="400"></td></tr>
<tr><td align='center'>      

    <table align='center' style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td><b>Créditos</b></td>
    <td><label id='credits'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Placa</b></td><td><label id='property'></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Chassi_final</b></td><td><label id='chassi_final'></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Cidade</b></td><td><label id='cidade'></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Estado</b></td><td><label id='uf'></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Marca</b></td><td><label id='marca'></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Modelo</b></td><td><label id='modelo'></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Ano</b></td><td><label id='ano'></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Cor</b></td><td><label id='cor'></label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Situa&ccedil;&atilde;o</b></td>
    <td><label id="situacao"></label></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</td></tr>
</tbody></table>    
</form>

<div align="center" id="myData" name="myData"></div>

<script>
    var token='';
    var vehicledata = "true";
    const checkbox = document.getElementById('vehicledata')
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            vehicledata = "true";
        } else {
            vehicledata = "false";
        }
    })

    const imgInput = document.querySelector('input')
    const imgEl = document.querySelector('img')
 
    function enableUpload(){document.getElementById("btn_uploadfile").disabled = false;}
    function startFunc(){
        document.getElementById('localImage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }    

    imgInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
      if (imgInput.files && imgInput.files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          imgEl.src = e.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(imgInput.files[0]);
        document.getElementById('localImage').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("credits").innerHTML      = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        document.getElementById("property").innerHTML     = '';
        document.getElementById("chassi_final").innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById("cidade").innerHTML       = '';
        document.getElementById("uf").innerHTML           = '';
        document.getElementById("marca").innerHTML        = '';
        document.getElementById("modelo").innerHTML       = '';
        document.getElementById("ano").innerHTML          = '';
        document.getElementById("cor").innerHTML          = '';
        document.getElementById("situacao").innerHTML     = '';        
      }
    }) 

    const myForm  = document.getElementById("myForm");
    const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");

    myForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {

      token = document.getElementById('myToken').value;
      token = token.replace(/\s/g, '');
      if (token.length<32){
          alert("Token não pode conter espaços.");
          document.getElementById('myToken').focus();
          return;
      }

      document.getElementById('btn_uploadfile').innerHTML = 'Processando, Aguarde...'; 
      document.getElementById("btn_uploadfile").disabled = true;

      e.preventDefault();
      const endpoint = "http://alprbr.com:30300/alprbr";
      const form_data = new FormData();
      console.log(inpFile.files);
      form_data.append("inpFile", inpFile.files[0]);
      form_data.append("countrycode","br");
      form_data.append("token",token);
      form_data.append("vehicledata",vehicledata);
      form_data.append("imageurl","");

        fetch(endpoint, {method: "post", body: form_data })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('erro: ' + err);
            document.getElementById('btn_uploadfile').innerHTML = 'Enviar';
        });
        function appendData(data) {
           document.getElementById("credits").innerHTML      = data.credits;
           document.getElementById("property").innerHTML     = data.property;
           document.getElementById("chassi_final").innerHTML = data.chassi_final;
           document.getElementById("cidade").innerHTML       = data.cidade;
           document.getElementById("uf").innerHTML           = data.uf;
           document.getElementById("marca").innerHTML        = data.marca;
           document.getElementById("modelo").innerHTML       = data.modelo;
           document.getElementById("ano").innerHTML          = data.ano;
           document.getElementById("cor").innerHTML          = data.cor;
           document.getElementById("situacao").innerHTML     = data.situacao;
           document.getElementById('btn_uploadfile').innerHTML = 'Enviar';           
        }   
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the function of the ESP32CAM sketch that posts image and data to Node-Red but arrive in the wrong place:
The image arrives at:  msg.req.files[0].buffer
and the data: msg.req.headers.countrycode, msg.req.headers.token, etc...

Question:
What must change at the ESP32CAM sketch below so all those variable and image that are under msg.req. are arriving under msg.peyload. ?

```
String postImage() {                      //post image directly to ALPRBR_API no storage
  String getAll;
  String getBody;

  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if(!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  
  Serial.println("Connecting to server: " + preferences.getString("serverName"));
  preferences.begin("AppParms", true); 
  
  if (client.connect(preferences.getString("serverName").c_str(), preferences.getString("serverPort").toInt())) {
    Serial.println("Connection successful!");    
    String head = "--ALPRBR\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imageFile\"; filename=\"esp32-cam.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
    String tail = "\r\n--ALPRBR--\r\n";

    uint32_t imageLen = fb->len;
    uint32_t extraLen = head.length() + tail.length();
    uint32_t totalLen = imageLen + extraLen;
  
    client.println("POST " + preferences.getString("serverPath") + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + preferences.getString("serverName"));
    client.println("Content-Length: " + String(totalLen));
    client.println("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=ALPRBR");
    client.println("token: " + preferences.getString("token"));
    client.println("countrycode: " + preferences.getString("countrycode"));
    client.println("vehicledata: true");  
    client.println("imageurl: ESP32CAM");  
    client.println();
    client.print(head);
  
    uint8_t *fbBuf = fb->buf;
    size_t fbLen = fb->len;
    for (size_t n=0; n<fbLen; n=n+1024) {
      if (n+1024 < fbLen) {
        client.write(fbBuf, 1024);
        fbBuf += 1024;
      }
      else if (fbLen%1024>0) {
        size_t remainder = fbLen%1024;
        client.write(fbBuf, remainder);
      }
    }   
    client.print(tail);
    
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    
    int timoutTimer = 10000;
    long startTimer = millis();
    boolean state = false;
    
    while ((startTimer + timoutTimer) > millis()) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(100);      
      while (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        if (c == '\n') {
          if (getAll.length()==0) { state=true; }
          getAll = "";
        }
        else if (c != '\r') { getAll += String(c); }
        if (state==true) { getBody += String(c); }
        startTimer = millis();
      }
      if (getBody.length()>0) { break; }
    }
    Serial.println();
    client.stop();
    Serial.println(getBody);
  }
  else {
    getBody = "Connection to " + String(preferences.getString("serverName")) +  " failed.";
    Serial.println(getBody);
  }
  preferences.end();
  return getBody;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found I will have to encode the image as base64 but was focusing on posting data and image properly first. I don't understand how to achieve what you propose. You say "before Serial.println()" I don't see where you are referring to. Also, how do I send the image as HTTP body? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I do not understand "Part of your head should be as HTTP headers", could you provide an example? Also, how do I send the image as HTTP body? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean client.print(head); must come before client.println("POST " + preferences.getString("serverPath") + " HTTP/1.1");?

Comment: Sorry my apology, i was reading it on my phone, and misread some of the code. Now I'm on my Mac, and it seems that your ESP32 is in order. Please ignore all my previous comments (i will delete it).

Comment: No problem. Yes, the code works, just posts the data and image on different places compared with the http and Kodular placement. I would like them all to use the same Node-Red flow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the end I sorted out the problem the following way:
The code to transfer image and data to Node-Red is:

```
String postImage() {
  String imageurl = "esp32cam";
  String httpResponse, targetURL;
  int httpResponseCode;

  camera_fb_t *fb = NULL;
  fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }

  String imgBuffer;
  char *input = (char *)fb->buf;
  char output[base64_enc_len(3)];
  for (int i=0;i<fb->len;i++) {
    base64_encode(output, (input++), 3);
    //if (i%3==0) imgBuffer += urlencode(String(output));
    if (i%3==0) imgBuffer += String(output);
  }

  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);

  preferences.begin("AppParms", true);
  pDBG("Connecting to server: ");
  pDBGln(preferences.getString("serverName"));
  //client.setInsecure(); //skip https verification
  
  HTTPClient http;
  http.setTimeout(5000);
  targetURL = "http://" + preferences.getString("serverName") + ":" + preferences.getString("serverPort") + preferences.getString("serverPath");
  pDBGln("Conecting to: " + targetURL);
  http.begin(targetURL);  //Specify destination for HTTP request
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  http.addHeader("imageurl", imageurl);
  http.addHeader("token", preferences.getString("token"));
  http.addHeader("countrycode", preferences.getString("countrycode"));
  http.addHeader("vehicledata", "true");
  http.addHeader("base64image", imgBuffer);

  pDBGln("Posting Now...");      
  httpResponseCode = http.POST("imageurl=" + imageurl + "&token=" + preferences.getString("token") + "&countrycode=" + preferences.getString("countrycode") + "&vehicledata=true");
  httpResponse     = http.getString();
  http.end();  //Free the resources
  preferences.end();
  pDBGln(httpResponse);
  return httpResponse;
}
```

At the top I declared the library as follows:

```
#include "Base64.h"
```

//https://github.com/fustyles/Arduino/blob/master/ESP32-CAM_Base64/ESP32-CAM_Base64.ino

I added the libraries Base64.h and Base64.cpp as part of the sketch in tabs.

All this data + image arrive at Node-Red at msg.req.headers so some code was required to adjust for that.

Comment: You can use `base64::encode(fb->buf, fb->len)` after including `#include "base64.h"` [base64.h](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/base64.h)